# media_handle_sideload on a file already on server

Tags: uploads

I want to attach a file already on server but outside the wp uploads directory to a post, so I tried the `media_handle_sideload` and used the `download_url()` on the file's URL I'm trying to attach, however for some reason, the `download_url` cannot access my server, is there a work around that I can do so instead of giving `media_handle_sideload` a $_FILES array I can give it the file absolute path? Or can I move a file already on server to the temp folder?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by simulating a $_FILES array:

```
$file_array = array(
            'name' => basename( $file_path ),
            'type' => $url_type,
            'tmp_name' => $file_path,
            'error' => 0,
            'size' => filesize( $file_path )
        );
```

And then

```
$att_id = media_handle_sideload( $file_array, $post_id );
```

As  simple as this..